# How to check how many of 100 matrices of equal dimensions are equal?

Tags: r

I currently have 100 generated matrices, and would like to verify how many pairs of these 100 generated matrices are equal. They have the same dimensions, 1000 by 1000. the function I am using is:

```
equalcheck <- function(x, y) is.matrix(x) && is.matrix(y) && dim(x) == dim(y) && all(x == y)
```

Is there a way to conduct this test without resorting to 100 choose 2 complexities?

Comment: in what a structure you stored the 100 matrices?

Comment: create some hash function based on elements of the matrix (perhaps sampling).  Sort the hash values to find duplicates, may create false positives, do element by element comparison of the hash colluded matrices.

Comment: these matrices exist as standalone objects, such as `mat.1`, `mat.2`, etc. I evaluate them using `eval(parse(text=paste0("mat.", i)))` where `i` is the index of a potential loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@karakfa had the right idea. We can use hashes to find out which matricies are the same or different, depending on your needs.

```
library(dplyr)

# Create all your matricies
x = matrix(1:100, nrow=10)
y = matrix(1:100, nrow=10)
z = matrix(101:200, nrow=10)

# Get a list of all objects
lst = lapply(mget(ls()), function(obj) {
    if (is.matrix(obj)) { 
        obj 
    } else { 
        NULL 
    }
})

# Filter out NULLs
lst = Filter(Negate(is.null), lst)

# Create a list of hashes
md5s = lapply(lst, function(obj) digest::digest(obj))

# Create a dataframe of the object names and hashes
df = data_frame(obj=names(lst), md5=unlist(md5s))

# Create a count to find those that are or are not unique
df %>%
    group_by(md5) %>%
    summarise(n = n())

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  md5                                  n
  <chr>                            <int>
1 2511f4beaee85d31d7e2e7746db9f627     2
2 502156778a19de62d2db1832bbe201e2     1
```